Frozen woman gains life back in the 80's
I remember watching this movie in the 90's, but the movie was probably released in the 80's. 
It is about a girl that is cursed in medieval times and is frozen/turned a doll.
Then, for some reason, she wakes up in the 80's and have no clue how to live in this new era. I think she ends up like a mannequin, but I not sure if this really happens.

I don't remember any of the actors.
The plot has some similarities with Mannequin (1987), but is not this movie.



The plot has some similarities with Mannequin (1987), but is not this movie.

Perhaps it's the unfortunate sequel...Mannequin Two: On the Move (1991)




A thousand years ago in the kingdom of Hauptmann-Koenig, Prince William (William Ragsdale) wants to marry his beloved Jessie (Kristy Swanson), a peasant girl. But his mother does not approve and has an evil sorcerer (Terry Kiser) trick the Prince into putting a necklace on Jessie, which turns her into a wooden icon for 1000 years (or until she finds true love in a foreign land).
A thousand years later, Jason Williamson (Ragsdale) is hired to work in Prince & Company's visual display department, which is headed by flamboyant window dresser Hollywood Montrose (Meshach Taylor). As a tribute to Hauptmann-Koenig, the Enchanted Peasant Girl is being sent to Prince & Company for a window display. Jason removes the necklace, which awakens Jessie. She believes he is Prince William until he convinces her a thousand years have passed and he is not the Prince (although Jason and his mother mention his family history, leading the audience to believe that Jason is the descendant of the Prince).
Wikipedia

